# Issue with date format in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to enter a date as follows `11/03/2014` but excel keeps converting it to `11-03-2014`.

How can I retain the forward slash instead of hyphen.

Comment: Change the date format

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing your windows settings for Locale?

GO to Start and write "Locale", open "Change the date, time or number format".

there you can chose options for format date, etc.